# Antlr4 - Getting name of matched rule

Tags: antlr4

I'm creating a relatively simple grammar which parses and breaks down strings into sub-components. A simplified version of the grammer is shown below

```
stmt: location type ID;

location : 
          location_A
        | location_B
        | location_C
;

location_A : 'LOCATION TOKEN 1';
location_B : 'LOCATION TOKEN 2';
location_C : 'LOCATION TOKEN 3';
```

Within my listener I have implemented ExitLocation to catch the token matched by this rule, but I would also like to extract the rule name of the sub-rule with which the token was matched (i.e. location_A/B/C).

Is it possible, from within the listener, to determine which sub-rule matched the token found?

Best Wishes
Dines Madsen

Answer (score 3):

[Alternative labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) will help you here. *Decorate* all alternatives with a unique `#name`:

```
location
 : location_A #alt1
 | location_B #alt2
 | location_C #alt3
 ;
```

and in your listener and visitor, there are `enter`- and `exit`-methods created for these labels (`exitAlt1(...)`, `exitAlt2(...)`, ...).

Comment: Hi Bart.

It's a perfectly valid solutions, which I am trying to avoid, as it would mean having to modify the listener every time I change the location grammar :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up simply grabbing the context name from the child node. As this information is only required for debugging purposes, it should be enough:

```
public override void ExitLocations([NotNull] TagParserParser.LocationsContext context)
{
    try
    {
        this.myLocationToken = context.GetText();
        this.myLocationRule = context.children[0].GetType().Name;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to assign the result of the subrules (which are by default rule contexts) to a local variable and check that in your listeners:

```
location:
    value = location_A
    | value = location_B
    | value = location_C
;
```

`LocationContext.value` then contains the matched location rule.